# How to add characters to a date or str in pandas column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, date, datetime

There is a dataframe df

It contains columns df.date, type object. Example 2019-01-01

I want to add to every date this value 'T07:00:00+0000', so my desired output is 2019-01-01T07:00:00+0000.

I've tried

```
df.date + 'T07:00:00+0000', as the type of the column object
```

But got this error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Ok then, if it's datetime let's convert to string:

```
df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And got this error:

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Why is this happenning?

Comment: I don't know Pandas (other than it being a group of cute fuzzy creatures), but you should _not_ be trying to manipulate a `datetime` object in your Python code.  If you want to _view_ your date times in that format, then use a function designed to do that which outputs a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert date object to strings is for first solution and for next if want to use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) first convert `date` object to `datetime`s with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[date(2019,1,1)]})

df['date1'] = df.date.astype(str) + 'T07:00:00+0000'

df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + 'T07:00:00+0000'
print (df)
         date                     date1                     date2
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-01T07:00:00+0000  2019-01-01T07:00:00+0000
```

Reason for error 1:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'

For add strings to dates/datetimes is necessary converting to strings.

Reason for error 2:

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Pandas still poorly support `python date`s, so necessary converting to datetimes.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!